# JAX-WS Endpoint to Domino

Tags: java, jax-ws, xpages, lotus-domino

My Domino *Web Service Provider* broke when I upgraded the (Win64) server from 8.5.3FP2 to FP3. I wrote some information about it to [XPage forum](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/xpagesforum.nsf/topicThread.xsp?action=openDocument&documentId=B1FE).

Instead of fighting with Axis based legacy stuff I'd like to use JAX WS which comes with Java 1.6. I decided to try [this](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-hello-world-example/) very simple example. I copy pasted the code to a Java project on my Designer Eclipse, run it and the Web Service was up and running on my local machine: it responded and returned the WSDL.

Next I copy pasted the code to an NSF on server as Code/Java elements and changed:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

to

```
public HelloWorldPublisher()
```

and called this constructor from SSJS in XPage. I got this error:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModelerException : A
>   @WebService.targetNamespace must be specified on classes with no
>   package.  Class: HelloWorldImpl

The classes were in packages. I run it also with command line on Domino server JVM and got the same error. After googling I added this

```
@WebService(targetNamespace="http://mycompany.net/dev/ph")
```

to *HelloWorld* and

```
@WebService(endpointInterface="com.mkyong.ws.HelloWorld", targetNamespace="http://mycompany.net/dev/ph", portName="HelloWorldPort", name="HelloWorld", serviceName="HelloWorldService")
```

to *HelloWorldImpl* in NSF and run it. After that the web service seemed to be up and running!

Next I booted the server because it was slow and after that I have not seen the WSDL! I've run the code many times, restarted HTTP and tried removing `@WebService` attributes. I've also tried to run the code with command line on server again but that gives me always the above *@WebService.targetNamespace* error, I have no idea why.

Now I get always this to Domino console:

> **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.streaming.XMLStreamWriterFactory
>   (initialization failure)**   at
>   java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:140)   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.SDDocumentImpl.writeTo(SDDocumentImpl.java:266)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.publishWSDL(HttpAdapter.java:538)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:230)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.WSHttpHandler.handleExchange(WSHttpHandler.java:107)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.WSHttpHandler.handle(WSHttpHandler.java:92)
>   at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:77)   at
>   sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:77)   at
>   com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:80)   at
>   sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(ServerImpl.java:569)
>   at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:77)   at
>   sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(ServerImpl.java:541)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:897)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:919)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:738)

when accessing this URL on server:

```
http://localhost:9999/ws/hello?wsdl
```

I'm a bit surprised I get anything to Domino log because I think this uses JVM http server. I don't understand why it worked first and now it cannot find this class.

How do I publish JAX WS endpoint to Domino Server?

**EDIT**

I downloaded the JAX WS jars from here:

http://jax-ws.java.net/

and placed the them in *\jvm\lib\ext* folder. The WSDL URL started to work again! Also the endpoint URL has some information now. I don't know why I had to do this because the functionality should be included in JVM 1.6. Next I will try to use Domino objects in the endpoint code.

Is it possible to make JAX WS to use Domino http server?

thanks,

- Panu

Comment: JAX-WS is part of J2EE, not J2SE (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_XML_Web_Services)

Comment: OK and Domino comes with J2SE? My JAX WS client has worked fine on Domino server and as I wrote I even got the endpoint up and running once without adding any JARs. All this makes me believe that at least most of JAX WS is included in Domino.

Comment: Can we start putting these suggestions in answers instead of comments so that these questions stop showing up as unanswered, please?

Answer (score 1):

JAX-WS is already included in Notes/Domino.  I suspect there may have been some instability introduced within your server whilst you were round-tripping during development.

I've created custom providers and consumers within XPages applications c/w SSJS and Custom Java access without issue since 8.5.3 and in 9.0.

Are you past your issue now? (if so, can you close out this question accordingly please :-)

Comment: Thanks, that's great to hear! I got my existing Provider design element to work so I didn't go this route yet (explained behind the link to XPages forum). But I will try the JAX-WS approach with the next endpoint that I'll create.

Comment: Did I understand correctly that you can make an XPage to be an Endpoint? If yes it would be very interesting to get some more info.

Comment: @tony: could you provide some samples please?